# How to use Django paginator in a query-performance purpose?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I just read [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/pagination/) about Django pagination.

From the example, it seems to need to be used like this:

1. Load all the objects
2. Create Paginator object to split objects across pages.

Now, let's say I wan't to use pagination with a very long query that returns 100000 entries.
I takes a very long time to load all 100000 objects at once.

What I'd like to do is to load only 10 objects per page. Is there a way to do this using Django paginator, and maybe some limit/offset queries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Paginator doesn't load all objects to memory.  If you pass a queryset to Paginator then it uses `.count()` to get number of objects.

Comment: Ahhh! Just read [this too](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) that helped me to understand why. Thanks.